# Почему перетаскивание работает не правильно если появляется вторая картинка

Tags: javascript

```js
ball.onmousedown = function (event) {
    ball.style.position = 'absolute';
    ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
    // document.body.append(ball);
    let shiftX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let shiftY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

    function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
        ball.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
        ball.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
    }
    function onMouseMove(event) {
        moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
    ball.onmouseup = function () {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        ball.onmouseup = null;
    };
};

ball.ondragstart = function (event) {
    return false;
}
```

```html
<img
    src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
    alt="basket" id="basket" width="180" height="180">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="ball" width="80" height="80" id="ball">
</body>
```

```js
ball.onmousedown = function (event) {
    ball.style.position = 'absolute';
    ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
    // document.body.append(ball);
    let shiftX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let shiftY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

    function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
        ball.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
        ball.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
    }
    function onMouseMove(event) {
        moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
    ball.onmouseup = function () {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        ball.onmouseup = null;
    };
};

ball.ondragstart = function (event) {
    return false;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fatlet-torg.ru%2Fimage%2Fcache%2F%2Fcatalog%2F1c%2F00_00001959-800x800.jpg&tbnid=HcAoDYGgJyeSSM&vet=12ahUKEwjUu-SHqNGBAxWNCRAIHfDbCf8QMygBegQIARBx..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fatlet-torg.ru%2Fmyachik-naduvnoi-backetbol-nii&docid=wUEA_2qUX7X1nM&w=800&h=800&q=%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA&hl=ru&ved=2ahUKEwjUu-SHqNGBAxWNCRAIHfDbCf8QMygBegQIARBx' alt="ball" width="80" height="80" id="ball">
```